# number of execution increases as mouse enter the same link again and again

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am facing problem in jquery
i have the following code which contains jquery-ui-tooltip with custom content.

```
$('a').tooltip({   
        items: "a ,[title]",
        content: function() {
        $('a').mouseenter(function(e) {                 
            var tempid= $(this).attr('title');
            console.log("hhh "+tempid);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"page1.php",
        data:"id=tempid",
        error:function(){
        console.log(event);
        return "<P>Some Problem occured</p>";
        },
        success:function(e){
                console.log(event);
       }

             });

          });
    return "<p>ha hdj fj fkfod jf kjf ckfd fkj</p>";    

}    
})
```

Now the problem is that when mouse enter on any link ,then success part execute 1 times .when mouse enter on the same link then it executes twice and so on...

But i want it to execute only once even if mouse enter twice or more.

Comment: because whenever mouse enter teh element a new mouseenter handler gets registered

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: You could have a variable recording if `mouseenter` already happened once and run the ajax call under a if statement. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes i have tried this already. I want to show information to users when the mouse enter the link inside tooltip .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global variable to check if the mouse has already entered.

```
var hasNotEntered = true;
$('a').tooltip({
items: "a ,[title]",
content: function () {
    $('a').mouseenter(function (e) {
        if (hasNotEntered) {
            var tempid = $(this).attr('title');
            console.log("hhh " + tempid);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "page1.php",
                data: "id=tempid",
                error: function () {
                    console.log(event);
                    return "<P>Some Problem occured</p>";
                },
                success: function (e) {
                    console.log(event);
                }

            });


        }
    });
    return "<p>ha hdj fj fkfod jf kjf ckfd fkj</p>";

}
```

});

Comment: i have tried this one and it solves problem if i have only one link .

Comment: if there are many links then it works for only one link and code does not even execute for other links

Comment: If you have multiple links, which you did not tell us, you could use an array to keep track of the mouseEnters that have been triggered.

Comment: Something like
`var hasNotEntered = new Array()`
......
`If(hasNotEntered.indexOf($(this).attr('id'))!= undefined){
hasNotEntered[] = $(this).attr('id');
.....`